# position absolute, scrollable element, beneath content, interferes with scrolling of main content

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have a 'position:absolute;` menu **underneath** my main content.

I'm using snap.js to slide the content to the right, revealing the menu.

The menu should be be able to hold any number of items, so it needs to be `overflow:auto;` and therefore scrollable.

When the menu is `overflow:auto;` it stops the main content from scrolling (maybe the element behind is still scrolling).

This is currently happening on androids stock browser.

I need the `z-index:0;` menu beneath to be scrollable but also allow the `z-index:1;` main content to have normal scrolling functionality too.

I tried this jQuery as a first shot:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.snap-drawer').on('touchstart', function() {
        $('.snap-drawer').addClass('ovrflowAuto');
    });

    $('.snap-drawer').on('touchend', function() {
        $('.snap-drawer').removeClass('ovrflowAuto');
    });

});
```

No luck.

**HTML** (arbitrary menu items)

```
<div class="snap-drawers">
    <div class="snap-drawer snap-drawer-left">
         <h1>
        <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" class="clr_format">L'ART Magazine</a>
      </h1>

        <form method="get" id="snapform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" role="search">
            <input type="text" class="field" name="s" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" id="s" />
            <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" />
        </form> <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" class="clr_format">L'ART Magazine</a>

        <?php $menuParameters=a rray( 'theme_location'=>'sidebar-menu', 'container' => false, 'echo' => false, 'items_wrap' => '%3$s', 'depth' => 0, ); echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' ); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" class="clr_format">L'ART Magazine</a>
 <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" class="clr_format">L'ART Magazine</a>
 <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" class="clr_format">L'ART Magazine</a>
 <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" class="clr_format">L'ART Magazine</a>
 <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" class="clr_format">L'ART Magazine</a>
 <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" class="clr_format">L'ART Magazine</a>
 <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" class="clr_format">L'ART Magazine</a>
 <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" class="clr_format">L'ART Magazine</a>
 <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" class="clr_format">L'ART Magazine</a>
 <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" class="clr_format">L'ART Magazine</a>
 <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>" class="clr_format">L'ART Magazine</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .snap-drawers {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index:0;
    background-color:#222;
    text-align:center;
}
.snap-drawer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    left: auto;
    width: 265px;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: width 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.3s ease;
    transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
.snap-drawer > h1 {
    color:#ddd;
    font-size:1.5em;
    font-family:'Poiret One', cursive;
    padding:20px 0 20px 0;
}
.snap-drawer > a {
    background-color:#666;
    border-bottom:5px solid #222;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    width:100%;
    padding:15px 0 15px 0;
    color:#ddd;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:'News Cycle', sans-serif;
    font-size:1.2em;
}
.snap-drawer a:active {
    background-color:#444;
}
#snapform {
    padding:0 0 10px 0;
}
#snapform input {
    height:30px;
    border-radius:20px;
    width:80%;
    padding-left:30px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.snap-drawer-left {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
.snapjs-left .snap-drawer-right, .snapjs-right .snap-drawer-left {
    display: none;
}
```

**Content wrapper:**

```
div#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
    z-index:2;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I've have done push menu or off canvas menus which ever you like to call it, I used the natural index of the html elements instead of the z-index since some browsers have an issue with it. Then I used jQuery or JS to add a css class that triggered the slide. It also gave the two panels the ability to independently scroll and should do what you need.

I set up the html like this

```
<div class="wrap">                  // if z-index started here 
    <div class="left-panel"></div> // z-index is 0
    <div class="right-panel> // z-index is 1
       <button class="menu-btn">Button to slide the panel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the css **you can edit the panels individually to your requirements

```
wrap { width:100%; height:100%; }
left-panel { width:300px; height:100%; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; }
right-panel { 
     width:100%; 
     height:100%; 
     position:absolute; 
     top:0; left:0; 
     transition: left 0.5s ease; /* add vendors transitions */
}
right-panel.active { left:300px; /*width of left panel*/ }
.menu-btn { position:absolute; top: 1em; left:1em; }
```

Then just add you click event to the menu-btn to add the active class to the right-panel

```
$('.menu-btn').on('YOUREVENT', function() {
      $('.right-panel').addClass('active');
});
```

I know you were not exactly asking how to do the slide menu thing but I'm hoping that maybe the structure I did mine will help with you overflow scrolling problem. I have not run in to that issue doing it this way.

Comment: I found that this problem only appears in pre jelly bean androids so for the sake of an upcoming deadline I'll let it slide, but I shall give this a go after. Thank you.